# HtmlPage.save() doesn't preserve arabic characters

Tags: java, utf-8, htmlunit

Using **HtmlUnit 2.15**, trying to call myHtmlPage.save(file) on a page which has both English and Arabic content doesn't save the page in correct format. ??? (Question marks) are displayed in place of Arabic characters.

**Code snippet:**

```
File fileToSave = new File("D:\\abc.txt");
final HtmlPage startPage = webClient.getPage(baseUrl);
startPage.save(fileToSave);
```

Opening the saved page in browsers (chrome & IE8 both) or with editor (notepadd++) shows ?? for Arabic characters.

How to get the HtmlPage.save() to save with correct Arabic characters? Thanks in advance.

Comment: An example URL would be useful for everyone who wants to try it themself.

Comment: A sample URL (I should have given that in the beginning):    webClient.getPage("https://www.google.ae/");